# Parallel processing a large number of tasks

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have 10,000 csv files for which I have to open in Pandas and manipulate/transform using some of Pandas's function and save the new output to csv. Could I use a parallel process (for Windows) to make the work faster? I tried the following but no luck:

```
import pandas pd
import multiprocessing

def proc_file(file):
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
    df = df.reample('1S', how='sum')
    df.to_csv('C:\\newfile.csv')
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    files = ['C:\\file1.csv', ... 'C:\\file2.csv']

    for i in files:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=proc_file(i))
    p.start()
```

I don't think I have a good understanding of multiprocessing in Python.

Comment: At the very least, I think files and the for loop must be in a main function: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming

Comment: Incidentally, I think the question title should be changed, as it really doesn't much target the intersection of pandas specifically and python parallel processing.

Comment: The benefits of `multiprocessing` maybe somewhat limited by the amount of I/O required to read all the CSVs - reading from disk can't be parallelized with a typical disk drive, so if that ends up dominating the runtime, `multiprocessing` won't help. It could actually end up hurting, if your HDD needs constantly seek to different parts of its platter to concurrently read from many files.

Comment: @dano, can SSD's help? (instead of normal disk drive)

Comment: @user308827 Yeah, SSDs will behave much better here. You don't have to deal with the seek times you get with spinning media, and I believe at least some SSDs can do parallel reads/writes. At the very least performance shouldn't degrade beyond what you'd get with a sequential program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to close the pool later too:

```
import multiprocessing

# Maximum number of cpus to use at a time
max_threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count() - 1

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(max_threads)
list_files = pool.map(func,list_of_csvs)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

list_files can contain a list e.g. you could return the name of the altered csv from func()

Comment: Why do I need to close and join the pool? If I only care that I save each of my CSV files through my `def` function, does it really matter that I close and join?

Comment: it is just cleaner, indicating that no more data will be put into the queue.

Comment: @user308827 The `close`/`join` is good style, but it doesn't make any difference in behavior this case; the main process blocks until `pool.map` is complete, so the `Pool` will just get terminated when the main process ends with no ill-effects.

Comment: thanks, is there a situation where close/join might be needed?

Comment: @user308827 If the OP had done `pool.map_async` instead of `map`, it would definitely be needed. the `pool.terminate()` will get called as soon as the end of the main program is reached, which will kill all the workers in the pool. If they're still doing work, that work will get aborted. With `pool.map`, you know that all the work is done before you reach the end of the main process, but with `map_async`, there's a chance the work isn't finished yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
p = multiprocessing.Pool()
p.map(prof_file, files)
```

For this size, you really need a process pool, so that the cost of launching a process is offset by the work it does. [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) does exactly that: it transforms task parallelism (which is what you were doing) into [task parallelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_parallelism).

Comment: I believe this will do the job. Can I specify the number of workers to use? I will get back to you if everything works fine. Thanks @AmiTavory